# Represent $50+49+48$ and so on to zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus, wolfram-alpha

How do I mathematically represent the operation of adding $50$, for example, to continuous decrements by $1$ until we reach $0$ ? $50+49+48+47+\dots$ until we reach $0$. For example, how do I put this problem in a way that WolframAlpha would understand and solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically, you could write that as $$\sum_{i=0}^{50} (n-i)$$

which is the same as $$\sum_{i=0}^{50} i$$

Wolfram Alpha understands quite a bit of mathematical terms, so you can simply search for

```
sum of i for i from 0 to 50
```

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+i+for+i+from+0+to+50

Comment: Sorry...I have mistakenly edited your answers while posting mine....pls forgive me and rolled back the edited...

Comment: @tatan What the hell did you do to my answer?!

Comment: I am really sorry...please rolled it back...

Comment: @tatan lol no problem, no harm done.

Comment: I am glad you did not flag me and have my account blocked...

Comment: Thanks a lot for a well-written and comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sum of first $n$ natural numbers is given by

$$S_n=\frac {n (n+1)}{2}$$

Using this you can find your sum without any calculator...

Comment: That's pretty awesome. I didn't know that; thanks!

Comment: Happy to help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

In Wolfram|Alpha we can write:

$$\operatorname{sum}[\operatorname{i},\operatorname{i}=0..50]$$

giving $1275$.

Answer (score 0):

A Wolframalpha syntaxis for $$\sum_{k=a}^b g(k)$$  is

```
sum( g(k), k, a, b)
```

And it's even [surprisingly versatile symbolically](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28g%28n%29-g%28n-1%29,n,a,b%29)...

Your case is $a=0,\ b=50,\ g(k)=50-k$

*Side note:* There is a counterpart for $\int_a^b g(x)\,dx$

```
int(g(x), x, a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

In mathematical notation, this would be written as $\sum_{k=0}^{50}k$, but Wolfram|Alpha would rather see it as something like *sum of k from 0 to 50*, and they also have widgets. Of course, you would always use the formal method (the one on the first line) in a formal paper, proof, or even a forum like here, but if you are just wanting to calculate it, you could send it to Wolfram|Alpha in the form on the second line.